# Does frequency affect current in Photoelectric effect?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, photoelectric-effect

If frequency of light in a photoelectric effect experiment increases (assuming its already enough to ionize the electrons), apparently the current will remain unaffected. This is contradictory to the Phet demo for photoelectric effect. What gives? Is the Phet demo wrong?

https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/cheerpj/photoelectric/latest/photoelectric.html?simulation=photoelectric

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the relationship between photocurrent vs frequency?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/460237/)